# IE9 Defaulting to IE7, javascript bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I have this javascript that seems to be forcing IE9 into computability mode and forcing it to IE7. There are other areas of the website working properly that do not have this javascript code working on them, which leads me to believe something in this script is not compatible with IE9/IE7.

Basically, the code creates a pop up box when your mouse hovers over it. However if the pop up box displays over an image, the image shows through the pop up box as if it has precedence. I have tried changing the z-index on that div but no luck.

Any suggestions?

```
            jQuery('.bubbleInfo').each(function () {

                if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).find('#dpop').html()) != ''){ // start

                    var totalHeight = jQuery(this).height();

                    var distance = 15;
                    var time = 250;
                    var hideDelay = 150;

                    var hideDelayTimer = null;

                    var beingShown = false;
                    var shown = false;
                    var trigger = jQuery('.trigger', this);
                    var info = jQuery('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);


                    jQuery([trigger.get(0), info.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {
                    if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                    if (beingShown || shown) {
                        // don't trigger the animation again
                        return;
                    } else {
                        // reset position of info box
                        beingShown = true;

                        info.css({
                        top: (totalHeight+38),
                        left: -77,
                        display: 'block'd
                        }).animate({
                        top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                        opacity: 1
                        }, time, 'swing', function() {
                        beingShown = false;
                        shown = true;
                        });
                    }

                    return false;
                    }).mouseout(function () {
                    if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                    hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                        hideDelayTimer = null;
                        info.animate({
                        top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                        opacity: 0
                        }, time, 'swing', function () {
                        shown = false;
                        info.css('display', 'none');
                        });

                    }, hideDelay);

                    return false;
                    });

                } // end
```

Comment: which jquery version are you using? Any error in console?

Comment: Does this particular page have anything at all before the `DOCTYPE` (and is the doctype the same as on other, working pages?)

Comment: Yes the DOCTYPE is the same.

Comment: IE9 was being forced into compatibility mode, and reverting back to IE7, where the problem was. I forced the browser to stay in current IE version. We are only concerned with IE9+ problems so this is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

IE < 10 have issue in the jquery library version although IE10 supports all the version's of jquery.